# Converting Posix Threads to C# Threads and vice versa

Tags: c#, c, pthreads, posix

If I made a c++ function and compiled it to a dll that looks something like this:

```
public pthread& NanoSleep(pthread& myThread)
{
    nanosleep(1);
    return myThread;
}
```

Is there a way to use this in a c# class that anyone can think of? Is passing the thread actually necessary? I basically want to try to get a c# thread to sleep for 1 nanosecond. There is no real functional reason to do this. I just want to know if it can be done :)

NOTE: If C++/CLI takes care of it then wow that's awesome.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19354/Quick-C-CLI-Learn-C-CLI-in-less-than-10-minutes#A8

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3837405/more-precise-thread-sleep

Comment: That's not exactly what I'm asking. I'm asking more if using C++/CLI is able to switch between using a c# thread and posix thread seamlessly but thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

.NET uses "managed threads". Under the hood, these are implemented by platform-specific threads. For example, Win32 threads on Windows. There is no one-to-one mapping between managed threads and platform-specific threads though; a managed thread can be moved between platform threads and processor cores. I'd assume that Mono implements managed threads by pthreads on Linux. But even if you determine the pthread that a managed thread currently runs on, you couldn't use it to pause the managed thread reliably.

Comment: Is this basically what you're saying (sorry but it's a over my head haha): pthreads don't compile down to .net threads when using c++/cli?

Answer (score 0):

Using c++/CLI on windows *should* allow you to wrap a pthread in a managed class (say you call it, Posix.NET.Thread) and use that *instead* of the System.Threading.Thread provided in .NET.

I suspect that even in your C/C++ code above that the pthread is really a Windows thread underneath, but I don't know there.

On Linux, you could use Mono.NET, and I'm quite sure that the implementation of System.Threading.Thread underneath on Linux would be a pthread.  Which is what dtb implied, but also was referring to other issues.  I can't verify that, but I would be surprised to find otherwise.

If your goal is actually to get sub millisecond time resolution, you don't want to rely solely on  thread sleep call anyway (managed or pthread).

On windows, in c++ there's the high-res timer:http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964692%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

And in .NET(c#) there's System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch class that wraps that high-res timer.

So you can sleep the thread, if you need to wait for >~30ms, and then poll the high-res timer for resolution higher than ~30ms.